# setInterval in UseEffect getting call 2/4 times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-effect

Hi want to hit useEffect just once, but its happening that its getting called 2-3 times , I tried wrapping the function in another but code starts to brake, can you guys help

need to call successHandler, but it is getting called over n over while it

```
  const { successHandler } = props; 
  const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(10); 
  const fileType = getFileType(props.fileName); 

  React.useEffect(() => { 
         function progress() { 
            setCompleted(prevCompleted => { 
               if (prevCompleted >= 100) { 
                   successHandler(); 
                   return 100; 
               } 
              return prevCompleted + 10; }); 
         } 
         const timer = setInterval(progress, 500); 
 
         return () => { clearInterval(timer); }; 
      }, [successHandler]);
```

Comment: `
  const { successHandler } = props;
  const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(10);
  const fileType = getFileType(props.fileName);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function progress() {
      setCompleted(prevCompleted => {
        if (prevCompleted >= 100) {
          successHandler();
          return 100;
        }
        return prevCompleted + 10;
      });
    }

    const timer = setInterval(progress, 500);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [successHandler]);

`

Comment: remove `[successHandler]` dependency and change it to `[]` if you only want it to call once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `useEffect` is called multiple times, then it means that something in its dependencies changes. In your case `successHandler` changes. See where it comes from, maybe you need to use `useCallback` for it to make sure it doesn't change on re-render.

For example this will re-run `useEffect` on each re-render, because `f` will be a new function each time:

```
const f = () => {};
useEffect(() => { f(); }, [f]);
```

While this will run `useEffect` only once, since `useCallback` memoizes the function and `f` will not change on each re-render:

```
const f = useCallback(() => {}, []);
useEffect(() => { f(); }, [f]);
```

Later edit - I missunderstood the question. Try to rewrite it like this:

```
const { successHandler } = props;
const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(10);
const fileType = getFileType(props.fileName);

React.useEffect(() => {
  function progress() {
    setCompleted(prevCompleted => Math.max(100, prevCompleted + 10));
  }
  const timer = setInterval(progress, 500);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (completed === 100) {
    successHandler();
  }
}, [completed, successHandler]);
```

This way `successHandler` should only be called once when completed becomes 100 (given that successHandler does not change).

You probably want to stop the time when progress is 100 too, so you can do it like this:

```
const { successHandler } = props;
const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(10);
const fileType = getFileType(props.fileName);
const timer = React.useRef(null);

const stopTimer = React.useCallback(() => {
  if (timer.current) {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    timer.current = null;
  }
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  function progress() {
    setCompleted(prevCompleted => Math.max(100, prevCompleted + 10));
  }
  timer.current = setInterval(progress, 500);
  return stopTimer;
}, [stopTimer]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (completed === 100) {
    stopTimer();
    successHandler();
  }
}, [completed, stopTimer, successHandler]);
```

Comment: I tired it but its not happening as successHandler is getting invoxed from useEffect it self, when the progressbar reaches to 100 but its getting called two times , I tried removing it from dependencies as well, but it still does the same

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the question. So useEffect is executed once, but successHandler multiple times?

Comment: Maybe you need `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`? `setInterval` is supposed to repeatedly call `progress` function, so that's expected behaviour.

Comment: Or... I think I get it now. You want to call progress multiple times, but you expect the condition prevCompleted >= 100 to be met only once. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct sucessHandler is getting called multiple time

Comment: Or... I think I get it now. You want to call progress multiple times, but you expect the condition prevCompleted >= 100 to be met only once. Is that correct?

Yes that it , I even made it to === but it same

Comment: That's because the timer continues to run until the component is unmounted, so it will call progress() each 500ms which sets completed to 100 each time and calls successHandler(). See the updated example, that should fix it.

Comment: Figured it out , the reason was because the return was sending return 100 so it was getting triggered two times, so I increased it to 120 so only one call was happening , so much confusing, anyways thanks :)